# assign a value to a link between classes in an Ontology (RDF/XML serialisation) with Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, owl

I want to be able to automatically assign a value to a link connecting two classes in my ontology. There are only two values to be assigned to the link; that is the link will be assigned a values of 1 if the link is from a class with less number of subclasses connecting to it compared to the class the link is terminating, and assigned a value of 5 if the link is from the class with more number of subclasses connecting to it and if all the classes have equal number of subclasses then the link will be assigned a value of 5.

I can load my ontology in Jena and list all subclasses and superclasses of each class in my ontology.

This will help me traverse my RDF graph using any algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to annotate the links between nodes in an RDF graph, other than the predicate URI that they already have.

You have two choices, that I can see. The first is to keep a table outside the RDF graph that records weights. Suppose you have:

```
ex:Class1 a owl:Class.
ex:Class2 a owl:Class ;
          ex:myWeightedProperty ex:Class1.
```

and suppose that we want to assign a weight of 1.0 to this connection. You would have a separate data-structure recording:

```
    S      |      P                |        O      |    W
-----------------------------------------------------------
ex:Class2  | ex:myWeightedProperty | ex:Class1     |    1.0
```

This is compact and efficient, but obviously requires you to keep the information out-of-band with respect to the graph. In particular, it won't be saved when you serialize the graph to disk etc.

The second choice is to encode the information in the graph, using a form of reification (or you could just use the RDF reification vocabulary, but I think it's clearer to roll your own):

```
ex:Class1 a owl:Class.
ex:Class2 a owl:Class ;
          ex:linkTo [
             a ex:WeightedLink ;
             ex:predicate ex:myWeightedProperty ;
             ex:to ex:Class1 ;
             ex:weight 1.0
          ].
```

If I was doing this, I would include the direct property link as well (i.e. `ex:Class2 ex:myWeightedProperty ex:Class1`), because although it's arguably redundant it isn't much overhead and will make SPARQL queries a lot simpler in the case where you don't care about the weight.

Comment: Ian thank you very much. You have given me a positive start. I think the best option to my problem is the first one of keeping the table outside the RDF graph that records the weights as for now I'm on using the rdf:type property (is-a), I have reserved the ObjectProperty and Datatype Property first, I am not using them for now. Once again thank you .

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, you can mark it as such by ticking the green arrow next to what you feel is the best answer. This helps other users coming in future with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Ian Dickinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212708/1281433), there's not a direct way to do this in RDF.  RDF does have a reification vocabulary for talking about triples, and you could talk about the triple `Class1 relatedTo Class2`, calling it `triple789`, and then adding `triple789 hasValue 5`.  However, a graph having statements *about* a triple is not the same as the graph *containing* that triple.  However, it sounds like you have an OWL ontology, and OWL *does* provide a way of both asserting a statement and also saying something about it:  [annotations](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Annotations).

In OWL, which can be serialized as RDF, you can make arbitrary relationships between classes as annotations, which will not affect the *meaning* of the ontology, but can carry information that may be useful to other processing tools, or to human readers of the ontology.  In addition, other OWL constructs, such as axioms, including annotation axioms, can be annotated, too.  OWL annotations are nice in that they should be preserved by OWL processing tools, and you don't have to invent your own reification vocabulary.

Using annotations, you can define, e.g., `linkedTo` as an annotation property, then assert (as an annotation) `FirstClass linkedTo SecondClass`.  You could then annotate *that* annotation with another annotation property `linkValue` and the object `"5"^^xsd:integer`.  Here's what that looks like in RDF/XML and in N3.  Notice that, as Ian Dickinson suggested in his answer, this usage still includes the direct link between the classes (i.e., we have `FirstClass linksTo SecondClass`) which *will* make SPARQL queries easier, especially when the extra value is not necessary.

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:links="http://www.example.com/links#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.com/links"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/links#SecondClass">
    <links:linkedTo>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/links#FirstClass"/>
    </links:linkedTo>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/links#linkValue"/>
  <owl:Axiom>
    <links:linkValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    >5</links:linkValue>
    <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/links#FirstClass"/>
    <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/links#SecondClass"/>
    <owl:annotatedProperty>
      <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/links#linkedTo"/>
    </owl:annotatedProperty>
  </owl:Axiom>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
@prefix :        <http://www.example.com/links#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix links:   <http://www.example.com/links#> .

links:linkedTo
      a       owl:AnnotationProperty .

[]    a       owl:Axiom ;
      links:linkValue 5 ;
      owl:annotatedProperty
              links:linkedTo ;
      owl:annotatedSource links:SecondClass ;
      owl:annotatedTarget links:FirstClass .

links:linkValue
      a       owl:AnnotationProperty .

<http://www.example.com/links>
      a       owl:Ontology .

links:SecondClass
      a       owl:Class ;
      links:linkedTo links:FirstClass .

links:FirstClass
      a       owl:Class .
```

Just so that you can see the structure of the resulting OWL ontology (apart from its RDF serializations), here's the ontology in the OWL functional syntax, too:

```
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)

Ontology(<http://www.example.com/links>

Declaration(Class(<http://www.example.com/links#FirstClass>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.example.com/links#SecondClass>))
AnnotationAssertion(Annotation(<http://www.example.com/links#linkValue> "5"^^xsd:integer) <http://www.example.com/links#linkedTo> <http://www.example.com/links#SecondClass> <http://www.example.com/links#FirstClass>)
Declaration(AnnotationProperty(<http://www.example.com/links#linkValue>))
Declaration(AnnotationProperty(<http://www.example.com/links#linkedTo>))
)
```

Comment: Joshua thank you very much. It's true that I have an OWL ontology serialised as RDF/ML. I appreciate your advice and it's really helpfull.